# Losing the player board ability in the middle of the turn

Tags: ghost-stories

In a game the other day we came up in a situation where the blue player ended up in a complex situation:
He had selected the player board ability that lets him take the board action and also attack ghosts on the same turn. He took the board action that was to move a player, then a ghost. He moved a ghost to his own player board, and thereafter wanted to attack the ghost he moved. Then we realized that the ghost he moved was a ghost that blocks the player from using his player board ability. At this point, we ruled that he could not attack, as he had lost the player board ability in the middle of his turn.

You could argue that in most cases the player could have attacked first, then moved the ghost - but in this case he wanted to attack the ghost that was moved, and he could not reach it before it was moved.

We could not find a clarification for this. Did we rule it correctly?

Comment: i dont have the rules near at hand. Is the effect at the monster's spawn (right) or in the continuous effect (middle) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant rules:

> It may happen that a Taoist loses his  power because of a ghost
>   ability. He can recover it as soon as the  responsible ghost is
>   removed from his board.

I can't find anything in the rules that explicitly states when you lose your power, but I would assume that if you get them back instantly, that you can lose them instantly as well.

Regarding the symbol on the ghost card:

> As long as  this ghost is not defeated,  the power of the board  where
>   the ghost card has been placed cannot be used (place an  Inactive
>   Power token on the power stone of the board)

Even though this symbol might be in the immediate actions part of the ghost card, it is a ongoing effect that transfers to a new board when it is moved.

> The blue Taoist can act in a heartbeat. He may request villager’s help
>   AND attempt an exorcism in the  same turn, in any order

This isn't explicit either about when exactly your power is used. If the blue player's power is such that the use of the power occurs before the attempted exorcism, or the use of a village tile, than I would say that you can in fact still do both actions. But this seems to be a strange interpretation to me. Since every player in the game can already can use a village tile on their turn, I would interpret the use of the blue Taoist's power to be when he tries to exorcise a ghost after having already used a village tile.

Therefore, I agree with your interpretation that you cannot attempt an exorcism because you need to use your power in order to attempt an exorcism after having already used a village tile.